# I wanted to make a function of pangram

Tags: python

[image]

i coded this

```
def panagram(sen):
    sen= sen.replace(" ","")
    alphabets = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i",'j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',1]
    for words in sen:
        for letter in words:
            if letter.lower() in alphabets:
                alphabets.remove(letter)
            else:
                pass
    if len(alphabets)==1:
        return "PANAGRAM"
    else:
        return "Not Panagram"
```

but when i run it i got an error[image]

(PS i am a beginner this is my first question)

Comment: Remove letter.lower(), not letter.

Comment: You should remove letter.lower because there are no capital letters in your alphabet.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: thanks luk2302 it is working fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you removed the spaces from the string.
When the first loop is run it, as there are no spaces in the string, it instead of considering words directly takes up the letters.
For eg. if

`sen = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"`

when you remove spaces, it becomes

`"Thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog"`

The word then becomes a letter that means in first run

```
word = T
```

And then there is nothing itterable in a string character, that's why it gives error

You can either remove

```
sen= sen.replace(" ","")
```

Or the loop

```
for words in sen:
```

Just use

```
for letter in sen:
```

Also remove letter.lower() not lower, there is another problem in your string the letter h come twice, so when it is removed first time, there is nothing left to remove the second time, you can solve this by creating a set

```
a = set(sen)
```

Then you iterate through the set

Hope that helps!!

Comment: i removed .lower() and .replace() its working absolutely fine now